# How to efficiently create a summary dataframe using list of lists in python

Tags: pandas

I have a list as follows.

```
mylist = [["cat", "dog"], ["dog", "rat"], ["parrot", "cat"], ["mouse", "rat"], ["mouse", "cat"]]
```

I want to get a summary dataframe for each animal as follows.

```
         cat, dog, rat, parrot, mouse
cat       0,  1,   0,    1,      1
dog       1,  0,   1,    0,      0
rat       0,  1,   0,    0,      1
parrot    1,  0,   0,    0,      0
mouse     1,  0,   1,    0,      0
```

I am wondering if there is a standard way of doing this in pandas.

My current code is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
mylist = [["cat", "dog"], ["dog", "rat"], ["parrot", "cat"], ["mouse", "rat"], ["mouse", "cat"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
```

I am happy t provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it , with `stack` `str.get_dummies` and `dot`

```
#df=pd.DataFrame(mylist)
s=df.stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
s=s.T.dot(s)
s.values[tuple([np.arange(s.shape[0])]*2)] = 0
s
        cat  dog  mouse  parrot  rat
cat       0    1      1       1    0
dog       1    0      0       0    1
mouse     1    0      0       0    1
parrot    1    0      0       0    0
rat       0    1      1       0    0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a quick question. is there a simple way to transform my dataframe into something like this? `myoutput = [["cat", [0,1,1,1,0]], ...., ["rat", [0,1,1,0,0]]]`?

Comment: s.to_dict('l')
{'cat': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], 'dog': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 'mouse': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 'parrot': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'rat': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]} @EmJ

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a different approach using `pd.crosstab`,

```
idx = ['cat', 'dog', 'rat', 'parrot', 'mouse']

df1 = pd.crosstab(df[0], df[1]).reindex(index=idx, columns=idx, fill_value=0)

result = df1 + df1.T
```